# How to assign 2 names depending of value selected in input radio form?

Tags: php

I've created a basic website that requires the user to select a radio button.

I want a PHP file to retrieve the value of the radio button that was chosen and respond depending of the option selected.

Index.html:

```
    <form action="result.php" method="post">
<br>
<table>
<tr><td><input type="radio" name="MyRadio" value="1" checked="checked">First option</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="radio" name="MyRadio" value="2">Second option</td></tr>
<tr><td"><input type="radio" name="MyRadio" value="3">Third option</td></tr>
<tr><td"><input type="radio" name="MyRadio" value="4">Four option</td></tr>
</table>
<br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Show result"><br><br>
</div>
</form>
```

I was playing with PHP Form Handling to get the value name in next page using "`<?php echo $_POST["MyRadio"]; ?>.`

But I need that when the form is sent, the php file assigns 2 names depending on the value of the selected radio.

Example:

```
If MyRadio value is 1 $option=1, $price=10.
```

Other example:

```
If MyRadio value is 2 $option=2, $price=20.
```

Example result:

```
Hello, you have selected $option , the price is $price.
```

I was looking in w3schools about IF conditions and variables but I can't get it and I need an example.

I've also been kicking google for some days before open this thread and I can't find a reply.

If someone here can help me I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's no different from any other `if` statement.

```
if ($_POST['MyRadio'] == '1') {
    $option = 1;
    $price = 10;
} elseif ($_POST['MyRadio'] == '2') {
    $option = 2;
    $price = 20;
}
```

and so on for other values.

Comment: Hello. Many thanks for your answer. I got two questions now: 1) I must keep adding more values using if or elseif? I mean if I want add the value 3 I must add another elseif to the code you give me? And the other question: How I do to show the $option result in the result.php file? I tried using: <?php "Your code here" ?><html>Hello your option is $option and price is $price</html> but the result.php file show me $option and $price instead the value assigned. I tried also using echo "Your $option, the $price" inside php code but don't works. Sorry for ask too much and thank you again for help.

Comment: If you have lots of them, you could use an array instead of lots of `if` statements.

Comment: `<html>Hello your option is <?php echo $option;?>`

Comment: Thanks I will look for information about array to learn some new. And thanks for the <?php echo $option;?> now its working :)

Comment: This is really basic stuff, you need to learn the language from tutorials.

Comment: Yeah I have a lot of learn. Thank you I mark you as the best answer ;)